# May the youyeetooX1 bios, support any M.2 to SATA3.0 conversion card?

Tags: ssd, sata

Using a M.2 to SATA3.0 conversion card
(JMB585 or ASM1166 based)
would allow to build a NAS from a youyeetoo X1 motherboard.

Did any one manage to do that and would you know if it might be possible, possibly by setting bios options ?

For now a SATA drive simply plugged with such a card seems not recognised at startup by the bios of the youyeetoo X1.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Hardware Recs! As written this seems to be a question regarding a technical support request for existing hardware, rather than a recommendation for new hardware; as such, this is probably better suited for Super User rather than Hardware Recs. That said, in my experience drives attached to ASM1166-based M.2 adapter don't typically show up in the BIOS, they'll only show up once booted into the OS (assuming that the OS has proper support.) What OS are you using, and are you getting any error message there?